# Unable to mount root filesystem on RPi image boot under QEMU

Tags: mount, boot, raspberry-pi, kernel-panic

I am trying to boot HypriotOS (https://github.com/hypriot/image-builder-rpi/releases/) RPi images from QEMU

I am using the kernels from https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel and preparing the image for QEMU using https://github.com/duquesnay/prepare-hypriot-qemu

I've tested that the root partition in the image is mountable and it looks fine to me:

```
$ sudo fdisk -lu hypriotos-rpi-v1.1.3-qemu01.imgDisco hypriotos-rpi-v1.1.3-qemu01.img: 8 GiB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectores
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tipo de etiqueta de disco: dos
Identificador del disco: 0x00000000

Disposit.                        Inicio Comienzo    Final Sectores Tamaño Id Tipo
hypriotos-rpi-v1.1.3-qemu01.img1            2048   133119   131072    64M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
hypriotos-rpi-v1.1.3-qemu01.img2          133120 16777215 16644096     8G 83 Linux

$ sudo mount -o loop,offset=68157440 hypriotos-rpi-v1.1.3-qemu01.img /mnt/

$ ls /mnt/
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

However, when trying to boot with the following parameters it fails:

```
$ export APPEND_ARGS="root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rw loglevel=8 console=ttyAMA0,115200"

$ qemu-system-arm -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot \
    -dtb ../../qemu-rpi-kernel/versatile-pb.dtb -serial stdio -append "${APPEND_ARGS}" \
    -kernel ../../qemu-rpi-kernel/kernel-qemu-4.4.34-jessie \
    -net nic -net user,restrict=off -hda hypriotos-rpi-v1.1.3-qemu01.img
```

The output shows that `/dev/sda2` is detected on boot but for some reason the kernel keeps complaining about not being able to mount it:

[image: /dev/sda2 detected but not mounted]

Answer (score 0):

The key to solve this was strictly following the instructions about the DTB in https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel#choosing-a-kernel-image

> ## Choosing a kernel image
>
> This repository contains three types of kernel images:
>
> - `kernel-qemu-4.*.*-buster` are the most recent images, which are compatible with Raspbian Buster and Stretch. To use these images,
>     you'll need the versatile-pb.dtb file which is also contained in this
>     repository. Unless you are positive you need a different kernel, the
>     most recent of these images is probably what you want.
> - `kernel-qemu-4.*.*-stretch` are images compatible with Raspbian Stretch and Jessie. To use these images, you'll need the
>     `versatile-pb.dtb` file which is also contained in this repository.
> - `kernel-qemu-4.4.*-jessie` are images compatible with Raspbian Jessie and Wheezy.
> - `kernel-qemu-3.10.25-wheezy` is the original image from xecdesign.com, which is compatible with Raspbian Wheezy only.

This two commands successfully started the image:

Kernel 4.19.50-buster:

```
$ qemu-system-arm -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "${APPEND_ARGS}" -kernel ../../qemu-rpi-kernel/kernel-qemu-4.19.50-buster -dtb ../../qemu-rpi-kernel/versatile-pb.dtb -net nic -net user,restrict=off -drive file=hypriotos-rpi-v1.1.3-qemu01.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw
```

Kernel 4.4.34-jessie

```
$ qemu-system-arm -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "${APPEND_ARGS}" -kernel ../../qemu-rpi-kernel/kernel-qemu-4.4.34-jessie -net nic -net user,restrict=off -drive file=hypriotos-rpi-v1.1.3-qemu01.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw
```